# How to loop through grouped XML nodes

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML document in this format

```xml
<rss>
  <channel>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>img_32.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>2</id>
      <image>img_42.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>1</id>
      <image>img_52.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>3</id>
      <image>img_62.jpeg</image>
    </item>
    <item>
      <id>4</id>
      <image>img_72.jpeg</image>
    </item>
  </channel>
  </rss>
```

The ID node is not unique. What I'd like to do using PowerShell is group by the ID, then loop through the grouped items for each ID.

```
ID 1 has two images
  loop through the two images
    do something with it

ID 2 has one image
  loop through the one image
    do something with it

etc..
```

So far I have the following:

```psh
[xml]$xml = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://myfeedurl.xml")
$grouped = $xml.rss.channel.item | Group id
$grouped
```

Which returns

```
Count Name        Group
----- ----        -----
    2 1           {item}{item}
    1 2           {item}
    1 3           {item}
    1 4           {item}
```

But I can't figure how use this grouped information in order to end up with a list of unique grouped ID items so i can easily loop through the images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Group` property of each item returned by `Group-Object` contains the group elements - all you need is a nested loop:

```
foreach($group in $grouped)
{
  "Processing images with id $($group.Name)"
  foreach($image in $group.Group)
  {
    "Processing $($image.Name)"
  }
}
```